# Why `astype(int)` changes the number?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Python 3.11.

I have some data which is nanosecond unix time but in float. I try to convert to int.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"float_time": [1698873816748837120.0, 1698873795853176060.0]}
)
df["time"] = df["float_time"].astype(int)
```

However, this fails

```
assert df.equals(
    pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "float_time": [1698873816748837120.0, 1698873795853176060.0],
            "time": [1698873816748837120, 1698873795853176060] # <- Note last number ends with 0
        }
    )
)
```

This succeeds

```
assert df.equals(
    pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "float_time": [1698873816748837120.0, 1698873795853176060.0],
            "time": [1698873816748837120, 1698873795853176064] # <- Note last number ends with 4
        }
    )
)
```

You can see `astype(int)` changes `1698873795853176060.0` to `1698873795853176064`.

I am wondering why `astype(int)` changes the number?

I was thinking decimals in the float may change, but didn't expect the integer part changes.

Could someone explains? Thanks!

Comment: but `assert 1698873816748837124 == 1698873816748837120.0` fails while `assert 1698873795853176060 == 1698873795853176060.0` succeeds.

Comment: Because floating point numbers are an approximation to real numbers: `1698873795853176060.0 == 1698873795853176064` vs `1698873795853176060.0 == 1698873795853176060`